# Can Anyone Tell Me How to Write Variable In Test Class

Tags: recursion

I have the following test class but when I try to deploy, I get variable does not exist and only in prod - Variable does not exist: CheckRecursive
Public Class:

```
public Class checkRecursive{
  private static boolean run = true;

  public static boolean runOnce(){
    if(run){
      run=false;
      return true;
    } else {
      return run;
    }
  }
}
```

Test Class:

```
 @isTest
    public class RecursiveTests {

        public static testmethod void testRecursive() {

            system.assert(CheckRecursive.runOnce());

            system.assert(!CheckRecursive.runOnce());
            system.assert(!CheckRecursive.runOnce());
            system.assert(!CheckRecursive.runOnce());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the `CheckRecursive` Apex class also being deployed along with the test class?

Comment: No, I'm only trying to deploy the test class and will then use it to cover the public class when I deploy that.

Comment: I'm only trying to deploy the test class and will then use it to cover the public class when I deploy that

Comment: I tried and then when I do that, I get 0% code coverage; in sandbox, the class gets 100%.

Comment: @SarahO Can you add the definition of the CheckRecursive class to the question? Also, are you deploying via a changeset with both the test and the class included? – Daniel Ballinger

Comment: I tried to deploy the RecursiveTests test class alone and it fails with Variable Doesn't Exist: CheckRecursive. I've tried them together too and get 0% code coverage error. checkRecursive added – SarahO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test class `RecursiveTests` and the `CheckRecursive` class need to be deployed together. The test class won't work without the class that it depends on. And `CheckRecursive` won't deploy without a corresponding test class to, at the very least, give it coverage.

Comment: @SarahO Can you add the definition of the `CheckRecursive` class to the question? Also, are you deploying via a changeset with both the test and the class included?

Comment: @SarahO They definitely need to be in the same change set. Can you try deploying them both together in the same change set and relaying back any results?

Comment: Definitely.  Doing it now.

Comment: I'm still failing to 0% code coverage: Your code coverage is 0%. You need at least 75% coverage to complete this deployment.
-checkRecursive

Comment: @SarahO What is the code coverage status in the org you are deploying to before trying the changeset? I.e. Try just running all the test cases in the target org first.

Comment: This worked, I used the test class to deploy and I think that was my problem, I wasn't sure that I could use it!  Thank you, Daniel Ballinger!